# Django's Count with relationship spans

Tags: python, django, count

Here are the relevant models:

```
class WhatToWearCandidates(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=False, blank=False, related_name="outfit_candidates")
    look = models.ForeignKey(StyleLook, null=False, blank=False, related_name="outfit_candidates")

class StyleLook(models.Model):
    # Non important attributes

class LookItem(models.Model):
    look = models.ForeignKey(StyleLook, null=False, blank=False, related_name="lookitems")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, blank=False, related_name="looks")
```

I'll explain this, each WhatToWearCandidates has a StyleLook and Profile, for each profile we show the correct looks to them. StyleLook just contains details about itself.

Each StyleLook is composed of Products, in the table LookItem we connect which StyleLooks contain which Products.

**QUESTION**: I'm trying to collect the WhatToWearCandidates that contain 4 or fewer Products efficiently.

I'm trying to use django's `annotate()` class

```
all_candidates = WhatToWearCandidates.objects.filter(
        look__lookitems__item__assignment=assignment.id,  # This is to filter based on Products that belong in the current Assignment
        profile_id=1,  #  Example profile
        look_id=15  # Testing with 1 single look for the proper profile
    ).values('look_id').annotate(lcount=Count('look__lookitems'))
```

From the debugger `all_candidates` prints to `[{'look__id': 15L, 'lcount': 1}]`. I know that this look contains 6 products, so I expected lcount to equal 6.

To double check I tried a similar query from `StyleLook` instead.

```
StyleLook.objects.filter(id__in=[15]).values('id').annotate(lcount=Count('lookitems'))
```

This returns `[{'id': 15L, 'lcount': 6}]`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get `lcount` to equal 6 in the `WhatToWearCandidates` query?

Comment: I ended up redesigning how to access the data I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably running into problems with [default ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) in one of your models. Try adding `.order_by()` to the end of the query:

```
all_candidates = WhatToWearCandidates.objects.filter(
    look__lookitems__item__assignment=assignment.id,
    profile_id=1,
).values('look_id').annotate(lcount=Count('look__lookitems')).order_by()
```